# Microphone recording problems where vowels are buzzing at a high pitch

Tags: vocals, microphone-technique

Can someone help me with this... I have a rode NT usb mic. It's a nice mic, but it squeaks a high pitch only on vowels. It's really frustrating because I cant EQ all it out without making the vocal sound bad. Is it the mic or do I need to have different settings. Also is there a name for this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: 'buzzing' … 'squeaking'… the two terms don't give a picture of what the issue is. If you can hear the mic through your speakers while this is happening, switch off the speakers, or at least don't route the mic through them.

Comment: possibly a sampling rate or driver issue?